# Enable Multiple Page Aliases

Tags: kentico

How can I get Kentico to show multiple aliases on the 'Page Alias' tab? I've seen screen shots of other setups that have this. We have an MVC setup that I understand hasn't got support for multiple aliases, but we'd like to use this feature. Is it possible to change a setting even at the DB level to enable this?

Comment: I am afraid but this does not make much sense as the Page alias field is used e.g. to build a menu or the alias path, in case you want to have something different in the URL. I think you are confusing it with the Page aliases used for multiple URLs for one page.

Comment: Yes the page aliases used for multiple URLs for one page is what we're wanting. It seems like you're understanding the question - in what way is it unclear?

Comment: Well, the Page alias in the content only page types is the alias which is displayed e.g. in the menu, or if you want to have it different from the DocumentName. It is not the page alias used to build NodeAliasPath. Also, when using MVC approach, it does not make much sense to have them specified in the admin UI since all the routes - and als the "page aliases" are handled in your MVC code and routes setup.